# I want to calculate whitespace or gap between the two words?

Tags: c++

This is my code and i am getting only zero's, please help me understand why?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a="";
    cin>>a;
    int m=a.length(),count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] == ' ' || a[i] == '\t' || a[i] == '\n' )
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting 0s?

Comment: what is your input to `a`?

Comment: `std::isspace` might be helpful instead of checking for every possible whitespace character.

Comment: `cin>>a` will only get you one word and not the whole string. Look up how to get whole string from user (`getline()`)

Comment: Minus one for the rant at the end.

Comment: The formatting options are there for a reason. You needed to provide more details for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

When you read strings with `>>` it reads white-space ***delimited*** words. In short, you can't use it to read multi-word sentences. I recommend you use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking input incorrectly , try this to take input (which will contain white spaces ofcourse)

std::getline(std::cin,a);

other part of your code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[The manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)** when you accept input using `>>` it **skips** any leading spaces.

So any spaces you type before the word get lost and are not placed in your string.

Try [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::getline(std::cin, a); // reads in spaces too
```